# Block access to webpage without login details

Tags: php, html, database, authentication

I have researched this problem a lot and I guess because I am new to PHP, I can't seem to implement the solutions from other questions similar to my own to my own code. Either way, here is my code below and a thank you in advance for any help I may get.

login.php:

```html
<?php
 include '../includes/inc.header.php';
?>

<body id="body">
 <title>Please Login</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/login.css">
 <div id="sign-In">
  <img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/locked-icon-28008.png"/>
  <h3>Login Here</h3>
  <form method="POST" action="connectivity.php">
   <br/>
   <input type="text" name="userName" size="40" placeholder="Username" id="user">
   <input type="password" name="pass" size="40" placeholder="Password" id="user">
   <br/>
   <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log-In">
  </form>
  </fieldset>
 </div>
</body>
```

connectivity.php:

```html
<?php
    
    session_start();
    
 define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
 define('DB_USER', 'root');
 define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
 define('DB_NAME', 'server-temp');
 
    $con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
    $db=mysqli_select_db($con, DB_NAME) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

        if(isset($_POST['userName'])) {

         $query = "SELECT *  FROM login where userName = '$_POST[userName]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'";
         $query = mysqli_query($con,$query);
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
   
             if(!empty($row['userName']) AND !empty($row['pass'])) {
              
              $_SESSION['ID'] = $row['UserNameID'];
              header('location: ../main-page/index.php');
                    exit();

             }else {
                 
              header('location: login.php');
             }
            }
   
   $_SESSION['ID'] = 1;
?>
```

index.php:

```html
<?php
 
 include '../includes/inc.header.php';
 include '../login/connectivity.php';
 
?>
 
<div id="temp1"></div>

<?php

 include '../includes/inc.footer.php';

?>
```

Here is a screenshot of the database table values:

[dbLoginTbl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCmUs.png)

The Header and footer includes doesn't contain any code related to the login form, hence the reason it does not need to be included. Can anyone tell me what code is needed so I can overcome this small but necessary hiccup. Thank you.

Comment: What you want, hide header and footer if user not authenticated?

Comment: No the main page, index.php, would block any access to itself unless the user has logged in. Ignore my header and footers, they are for other things.

Comment: for that simply check session variable with if statement and include that main section into that condition. For success full login set session variables and to restrict something just check session variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this.

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../includes/inc.header.php';
include '../login/connectivity.php';    
?>

<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['ID'])&&$_SESSION['ID']!=""){  //MUltiple session val better
?>
<div id="temp1"></div>
<?php 
}
else{
    echo "Access Denide!";
    //redirect to login page or just display message 
}
?>

<?php include '../includes/inc.footer.php'; ?>
```

**Note:** This is the simple way to hide something if user is not logged in. In this method we are just checking whether the session variable is set or not. You can set different session variables at the time of login and then use those variable to check whether a user is logged in or not. You can simply check whether the session is available or not using `isset()` and `empty()` methods.

Basically we are checking session to examine user login and block something, 
Here the simple form of code sample

```
//HEADER
//..................
if(isset($_SESSION['ID'])&&$_SESSION['ID']!=""){
    //Allowed content
    echo "Session variablefound and set, that why your content is .....";
    //Put your content here, 
    //you can put all allowed HTMl content here which are allowed to the authenticated user.
}
else{
    echo "Access Denied!";
}
//FOOTER
//..............................
```